# How to add rendered result information to a different table with the click of a button?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, model-view-controller, link-to

I'm fairly new to rails -- I want to be able to add any of the individual instances of information that is displayed through `<% @users.each do |user| %>` on the users index view to another table.

For example, on the click of a button, I'm assuming, a `link_to`, I want to be able to add the selected user to a "favorites" table, and then render the index of all favorites view. I know that this can be done through a form manually, but how do you do this without manually entering all of the information?

Answer (score 0):

### My Understanding:

1. On your page where you are showing <%= @users.each.do |user| %>, when you click a "(+ Add User to Favorites)" button, it will redirect you to a page where all of your user-favorites are shown, most likely `favorites#index`.

### My Assumptions:

1. You have a Favorites model having `user_id` and `favoriter_id` columns, where `user_id` is the target user, while `favoriter_id` is you, the actor-user. And a controller having CRUD methods such as `create` and `index`.
2. You have a `current_user` (Signed-in user) that is globally accessible in the controllers.

### Possible Approach:

#### yourpage.html.erb

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
  <%# ... %>
  <%= button_to "Add User to Favorites", Favorite.new(user: user) %>
  <%# ... %>
<% end %>
```

#### favorites_controller.rb

```
def create
  @favorite = Favorite.new(favorite_params)
  @favorite.favoriter = current_user

  if @favorite.save
    redirect_to favorites_path
  else
    redirect_to :back, alert: "Error saving Favorite"
  end
end

def index
  @favorites = Favorite.where(favoriter: current_user) 
end

private

def favorite_params
  params.require(:favorite).permit(:user_id)
end
```

#### Recommendations:

1. Use AJAX through unobtrusive-js upon click of "Add to Favorites Button", and do not redirect to any page upon click.
2. Use polymorphic association for the Favorite, as your application might grow and then you will need Favorite as well for others and not just users. (i.e. a Post you want to add to favorites)
3. Use shallow-nested resource path for `favorites#index`. So that you could access something like this:

   a. `/users/1/favorites` which shows list of Favorites by that user

   b. `/favorites` which shows list of all Favorites (possibly only accessible by admins)